# How to pass a std::array to a function template which can accept std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++14

I'm trying to write a template, which can accept some sequence containers:

```
template <typename S,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
              std::is_same<S, std::array<typename S::value_type>, S::size()>::value ||
              std::is_same<S, std::vector<typename S::value_type>>::value>>
std::string arr2String(const S& seqContainer) {
    std::stringstream res;
    for (const auto& element : seqContainer) {
        res << element << "|";
    }
    return res.str();
}
```

However, this can't be compiled because of `S::size()`. Obviously, there is no such a thing.

Is it possible to make such a template function, which can handle `std::vector` and `std::array`?

Comment: Exactly only `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Comment: I recommend you don't pass containers at all, and instead do like the standard library itself does it: Pass iterator ranges.

Comment: @Caleth, well, `std::vector` can represent any other sequence container in this case, such as `std::list`, `std::deque`. Right?

Comment: Alternatively have your function accept a `std::span` (or write your own equivalent that has implicitly converting constructors for `std::array` and `std::vector`)

Comment: Why does it have to be an array or a vector? Your code works for std::arrays, vectors, lists, deques, strings, C arrays, and spans. Why limit it to std::arrays and vectors only?

Comment: @user253751 In fact, it does work with other sequence containsers, I just simplified the sample.

Comment: @Yves but why not delete the second part and just have `template<typename S>`?

Comment: The simplest, easiest, most portable, most *old school* way is to accept a pair of iterators. C++98 all the way.

Comment: @user253751  Because I want to write another template, which can hold the other parameters that can't be deduced by this one.

Comment: @Yves in that case, you can use S::value_type which is implemented by all standard containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restrict your template to work for only `std::array` or `std::vector`, you can write some helper traits

```
template <typename>
struct is_array : std::false_type {}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct is_array<std::array<T, N>> : std::true_type {}

template <typename>
struct is_vector : std::false_type {}

template <typename... Ts>
struct is_vector<std::vector<Ts...>> : std::true_type {}

template <typename S,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
              is_array<S>::value ||
              is_vector<S>::value>>
std::string arr2String(const S& seqContainer) {
    std::stringstream res;
    for (const auto& element : seqContainer) {
        res << element << "|";
    }
    return res.str();
}
```

Otherwise you can SFINAE on something more general

```
template <typename S, typename = typename S::value_type>
std::string arr2String(const S& seqContainer) {
    std::stringstream res;
    for (const auto& element : seqContainer) {
        res << element << "|";
    }
    return res.str();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code could in fact be compiled if you instantiated an array and took its size, which is constexpr.

```
template <typename S,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_same<S, std::array<typename S::value_type, S{}.size()>>::value ||
            std::is_same<S, std::vector<typename S::value_type>>::value>>
std::string arr2String(const S& seqContainer) {
    std::stringstream res;
    for (const auto& element : seqContainer) {
        res << element << "|";
    }
    return res.str();
}
```

This of course would be problematic if default initialization of your value type is expensive.

Comment: Oh.. OK, I got it.

Comment: “This of course would be problematic if default initialization of your value type is expensive.” — Why? Nothing is being initialised at runtime here.

Comment: That one fails if you provide a vector as the expression S{}.size() is not constexpr for vector.

Comment: You are right, I somehow thought this could be fixed by rearranging the or expression, but all sub-expressions must of course be valid.